# jpql, fetching row with nullable variable

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, select, jpql

```
@Entity
class A{
   @OneToOne(optional=true)
   @JoinColumn(foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_USER"), nullable = true)
   B b;
   ..other fields...
}

@Entity 
class B{
   ....
}
```

I want to fetch rows of table A. 
I'm making jpql request

```
select new ADTO(b,..other fields(don't necessarily all)...) from A
```

(ADTO - [data transfer object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object))

And it's works, but just when A::b not null. 
If A::b is null this row doesn't selects.

And if i Have another request, it works good, even if rows content null A::b

```
select new ADTO(..filds without A::b...) from A
```

How can i select row with nullable A::b?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To not getting confused with aliases and entity names, I rename your Entities A and B to Parent and Child then it would be queried with an **outer join** like this:

```
select new ParentDTO(c, p.otherfield) from Parent p left join p.child c
```